# GlTexImage2D is doing nothing

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I've been trying million of combinations to pass a texture to a shader without any success. Here is a code that should add a second texture over a video (`OES_EXTERNAL_TEXTURE`). There is no `GL` error (I've verified all calls). The external texture is displayed (the video), but this other texture is always black in the shader (0, 0, 0, 1f).

This is how I'm initiating my 'overlay' texture.

```
            _texs = new int[1];
            GLES20.GlGenTextures (1, _texs, 0);
            _overlayId = _texs [0];

            GLES20.GlTexParameteri(GLES20.GlTexture2d, GLES20.GlTextureMinFilter,
                GLES20.GlNearest);
            GLES20.GlTexParameteri(GLES20.GlTexture2d, GLES20.GlTextureMagFilter,
                GLES20.GlLinear);
            GLES20.GlTexParameteri(GLES20.GlTexture2d, GLES20.GlTextureWrapS,
                GLES20.GlClampToEdge);
            GLES20.GlTexParameteri(GLES20.GlTexture2d, GLES20.GlTextureWrapT,
                GLES20.GlClampToEdge);

            GLES20.GlBindTexture(GLES20.GlTexture2d, _overlayId);

            GLES20.GlTexImage2D (GLES20.GlTexture2d, 0, GLES20.GlRgb, textureSide, textureSide, 0, GLES20.GlRgb, GLES20.GlUnsignedByte, ByteBuffer.Wrap(pixels));
            _overlayPosition = GLES20.GlGetUniformLocation (_glProgram, "overlay");
            GLES20.GlUniform1i (_overlayPosition, _overlayId);

            GLES20.GlBindTexture (GLES20.GlTexture2d, 0);
```

And this is how I'm drawing:

```
            GLES20.GlBindTexture(GLES20.GlTexture2d, _overlayId);
            _overlayPosition = GLES20.GlGetUniformLocation (_glProgram, "overlay");
            GLES20.GlUniform1i (_overlayPosition, _overlayId);

            GLES20.GlBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, _textureID    );
            _triangleVertices.Position (TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
            GLES20.GlVertexAttribPointer (_aPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GlFloat, false, TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, _triangleVertices);
            GLES20.GlEnableVertexAttribArray (_aPositionHandle);

            _textureVertices.Position (TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
            GLES20.GlVertexAttribPointer (_aTextureCoord, 2, GLES20.GlFloat, false, TEXTURE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, _textureVertices);
            GLES20.GlEnableVertexAttribArray (_aTextureCoord);

            Android.Opengl.Matrix.SetIdentityM (_MVPMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.GlUniformMatrix4fv (_uMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, _MVPMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.GlUniformMatrix4fv (_uSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, _STMatrix, 0);

            GLES20.GlDrawArrays(GLES20.GlTriangleStrip, 0, 4);
```

[Edit]

Finally got sampler2d texture to work by:

(In the texture initialization part) creating a texture:

```
            _texs = new int[1];
            GLES20.GlGenTextures (1, _texs, 0);
            _overlayTextureId = _texs [0];
```

Getting uniform location:

```
            _overlayTextureUniform = GLES20.GlGetUniformLocation (_glProgram, "overlay");
```

These params are needed, nothing more:

```
            GLES20.GlTexParameteri(GLES20.GlTexture2d, GLES20.GlTextureMinFilter, GLES20.GlNearest);
            GLES20.GlTexParameteri(GLES20.GlTexture2d, GLES20.GlTextureMagFilter, GLES20.GlLinear);
```

Creating texture from bitmap:

```
            GLUtils.TexImage2D (GLES20.GlTexture2d, 0, myBitmap, 0);
```

Setting texture in OpenGL context. This is a helper.

```
            setTexture2D (_overlayTextureUnit, _overlayTextureId, _overlayTextureUniform);
```

Freeing that bitmap:

```
            source.Recycle ();
```

=End of the texture initialization=

Here's the code of my helper:

```
       void setTexture2D(int textureUnit, int textureID, int uniformID) {
            GLES20.GlActiveTexture(GLES20.GlTexture0 + textureUnit);
            GLES20.GlBindTexture(GLES20.GlTexture2d, textureID);
            GLES20.GlUniform1i(uniformID, textureUnit);
        }
```

Anything special with this code? No. Was my former attempt well-coded? No. Two things helped a lot: 1. The small helper above, that is used to set OES and 2D textures in initialization and in onDrawFrame. 2. Debugging the image I was passing to the GlTexImage2D method, which finally happened to really be black. I changed pixels from float to int, and was casting to int before being done with arithmetics, this having either 0 or 255 values.

Comment: i think you must bind the texture first before you set the filters.

Comment: When you pass the texture ID through the uniform the ID depends on the active texture that is currently set and not the texture ID if I remember correctly. So when you want to use multiple textures in your shader program you need to set the active texture accordingly. So first set active texture to zero, bind the first texture and send zero as uniform. Then set active texture to 1, bind the second texture and send 1 through the uniform.

Comment: Also since more then this could be wrong you should first simply try to draw the overlay by removing the video part of your code. If possible always create some tools you use which can be tested separately.

Comment: @MaticOblak Thanks for this advice. It's so hard to debug this black box. And it definitely requires a barebone executable that just contains the OpenGL stuff, and only the debugged step as it needs a lot of deployments to achieve something good. I'm coding on Android so that's even worst if you know how long deploying can be.

Comment: I have one important question though. I'm coding with the assomption that it could be 'possible' that sampler2D and samplerExternalOES could not work together in certain development environment. Is this a completely false affirmation? I saw people rendering OES to another sampler2D before using it with another texture. That increases the level of difficulty for a novice like me, and this is another place where I spent a lot of time.